# Getting the current path in a LiveView

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

In a normal route:

`get /index, MyController, :index`

I can simply get the route from `Plug.Conn`'s path_info function.

However if I have a live route, how do I retrieve the current path?

`live /index, IndexLive`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the current uri using [handle_params callback](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#module-handle_params-3) which is called after mount and before render.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to actually use that callback in a template? I want to set an active class depending on the path.

Comment: In `*Web.*Live` module, define `def handle_params(_unsigned_params, uri, socket), do: {:noreply, assign(socket, uri: URI.parse(uri))}`, then you can use `@uri.path`.

Answer (score 6):

For those who are finding their way here a few years later, things have come a long way. If you find yourself needing the current path in **all views** (perhaps for a global navigation element) you'll lose your mind trying to put this on all views.

Making a module like this:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.SaveRequestUri do
  def on_mount(:save_request_uri, _params, _session, socket), do:
    {:cont, Phoenix.LiveView.attach_hook(socket, :save_request_path, :handle_params, &save_request_path/3)}

  defp save_request_path(_params, url, socket), do:
    {:cont, Phoenix.Component.assign(socket, :current_uri, URI.parse(url))}
end
```

And then dropping it into your live_session:

```
  live_session :some_session_name, on_mount: [{MyAppWeb.SaveRequestUri, :save_request_uri}] do
    scope "/", MyAppWeb do
      # Your routes
    end
  end
```

Will result in all `live_views` having a `@request_uri` available in the assigns.

**Note:** the reason phoenix doesn't automatically expose this for you is because the request path can be quite large for some apps; having this in all sockets, all the time, can be expensive. Like everything, a game of trade-offs.. hope this helps!

Comment: This is a great update. Just note that the on_mount function in your example shouldn't have the "end".